# how to populate Dynamic List Java

Tags: java, list, dynamic

I want to declare List as Dynamic

```
private static final List<KeyValue> columnDataList;
static {
    columnDataList = new ArrayList<DashColumnChartData.KeyValue>();
    columnDataList.add(new KeyValue("Russia1", "100", "500", "100", "100", "50"));
    columnDataList.add(new KeyValue("Canada1", "200", "500", "100", "100", "50"));
}
```

instead i want to create for this...

```
while (rs1.next()) {
    ArrayList<Comparable> chartDataList = new ArrayList<Comparable>();
    chartDataList.add(rs1.getString("region_id"));
    columnDataList = new ArrayList<DashColumnChartData.KeyValue>();
    columnDataList.add(new KeyValue(rs1.getString("country_id", rs1.getString("region_id", rs1.getString("state_id"));
}
```

how can I populate dynamic List and where to declare...

Comment: move the declaration&initialization of `columnDataList` outside (before) the `while` loop. Also fix the syntax of the usage of the `KeyValue` constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Java, local variables are bound to a scope. If you declare a local variable inside a loop, it is only available inside the loop. (Technically, you have a variable `chartDataList` *each per loop iteration*.) If you need to access the variable outside the loop, declare it in an outer scope, e.g., the surrounding method. In your 'static' example, the scope is the surrounding class.